# Dynamic menu link with dynamic page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have made a menu where data comes from mysql database. Menu link href is as:  href=**slider1.php?cat_id=" . $row['cat_id'] . "&product=" . $row['product'] . "**

database extract for menu

[image]

> My problem is : I am able to data for first level but for second and third level data,I am unable to show. With the below php code I am able to get `cat_id` of first level. I fail to understand how will I get second and third level id with the below php code.

```
<?php 
include('include/config.php');
if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
{
$level1= $_GET['cat_id'];
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
                                 a.img_id, 
                                 a.img_type, 
                                 a.img_size, 
                                 b.ad_id, 
                                 b.cus_id,
                                 b.ad_name,
                                 c.customer,
                                 c.mobile,
                                 d.product as category,
                                 e.product as subcategory,
                                 f.product as subcat
                                 FROM `image` a 
                                 INNER JOIN `advt` b
                                 ON a.ad_id=b.ad_id
                                 INNER JOIN `customer` c
                                 ON b.cus_id=c.cus_id
                                 INNER JOIN `category` d
                                ON b.category = d.cat_id 
                                INNER JOIN `category` e
                                ON b.subcategory = e.cat_id 
                                INNER JOIN `category` f
                                ON b.subcat = f.cat_id AND d.cat_id = '$level1'
                                 GROUP BY b.ad_id
                                 ")){ 


       $stmt->execute(); 
       $stmt->store_result(); 
       $stmt->bind_result($img_id, $img_type, $img_size, $ad_id, $cus_id, $ad_name, $customer, $mobile, $category, $subcategory, $subcat);   

       while($stmt->fetch()){ 
       ?>

        <tr class="example">

            <td><?php echo $ad_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $img_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cus_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ad_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $customer; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mobile; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $category; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $subcategory; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $subcat; ?></td>
         </tr>

        <?php
       } 
       $stmt->close();
       } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you INNER JOIN `category` as d, e and f. It's not necessary.

Comment: I wanted to show category, subcategory and subcat, that is why I used INNER JOIN

Comment: Then the subcategory and subcat should be from other tables? Now you are using exactly the same table.

Comment: Menu is dynamic menu. table is shown above